# setting up facebook 'insights for your web site' linkdoes not provide fb:admin tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

I've set up a facebook app and am now trying to get the fb:admin tags using the insights page at https://www.facebook.com/insights/.

when I click the 'insights for your web site' link the pop up does not give me the metatags that the help pages suggest should appear. As a result of this if I click the 'Get Insights' it throws the error;

```
No admin data found at root webpage http://www.domain.com/. Insights requires admin data at this root webpage for the specified URL www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem as well in the past.   Facebook appears to have fixed the bug and the meta tag is now shown when you click the "Add Your Domain" button:

[image]